# How to automate pop up window click OK button?

Tags: python, pywinauto

How to automate pop up window click button? I combine SWAPY and coding, but can not find necessary coding. I automate [Speech Filing System Tools for Speech Research](http://www.phon.ucl.ac.uk/resource/sfs/)

```
from pywinauto.application import Application
app = Application().Start(cmd_line=u'"C:\\Program     Files\\SFS\\Program\\sfswin.exe"')
afxab = app[u'sfswin - Unknown1']
afxab.Wait('ready')
afxbfdb = afxab.Unknown1
afxbfdb.Maximize()
toolbarwindow = afxab[u'5']
toolbar_button = toolbarwindow.Button(1)
toolbar_button.Click()
app.OpenDialog.Edit.set_text(ur'C:\Program Files\SFS\six.wav')
app.OpenDialog.Open.click_input()
app.OpenDialog.wait_not('visible')
afxab = app.window_(title_re="Open Audio File")
afxabButton1 = ButtonWrapper(afxab.Button.WrapperObject("OK")).Click
```

Comment: Which line is failed? And how is the traceback looking? Please be more specific. Sorry I can't help you if you create almost duplicated questions or don't accept correct answers.

Comment: The code ends with pop up windows. I did not include failed lines since I had tested several codes.

Comment: This big release introduces MS UI Automation (UIA) support. Just start from:
app = Application(backend='uia').start('your_app.exe').

Comment: Hmm... What is the failing line number? And what is the output? Please edit your question to add those.

Comment: I think you need to improve your programming skills first. Desktop UI automation is really complicated area. We try to make it simpler but there are still years of work forward. If you don't know how to provide Python traceback, it's time to learn Python in more details.

Comment: Thank you for comment. I am working skills. Trial and error,  practice, solution finding accompanied with theory is best way. I have updated code. The last line does not work.

Comment: Sorry for late answer, just went back from the holidays trip. The bottom line is obviously incorrect. `WrapperObject()` has no params. If you call `button1 = afxab.OKButton.wrapper_object()` then you're able to list all available methods by `print dir(button1)`. For example, `button1.click()` or `button1.click_input()`.